# Oracle: Stop trigger for some time

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I have created a trigger and I want to stop the trigger from executing its code for some time. Is there any function available in oracle for this.

Being more specific:-
I have to perform an action when a PO is created in oracle apps.
I need to find requisition number for this po which I will get by joining distributions and lines table. But when trigger is fired there wont be any data in lines and distribution table.

Comment: You mean, you want to put a time delay before the trigger starts executing?

Comment: yes you can say so...i want to put a delay on call of procedure my trigger is calling.

Comment: I want to perform some action when data get inserted in one table. For that I have created a trigger. Now when data in getting inserted in this table there is some related data under process of insertion in some other related table. Which I am fetching in my procedure called through the trigger and as a result I am getting no_data_found.

Comment: Given this condition you described above, how will you know how long should you postpone the trigger? What if the related data is still not finished entering after 10 sec?

Comment: Its just an assumption. If you can let me know any better way. I will be glad to implement it.

Comment: If the other processing is always happening then put all the related tasks in a procedure. Depending on what it's doing, the trigger action can be moved inside the same procedure; or the insert on the triggering table can be the last thing you do in the procedure?

Answer (score 0):

```
alter trigger <trigger_name> disable;
```

then to enable

```
alter trigger <trigger_name> enable;
```

You cannot delay your trigger, it will fire as soon as you perform the event on the table.

Answer (score 0):

There is no native database way to delay the trigger for some specified period of time.

In general you can enable or disable trigger using,

```
ALTER TRIGGER trigger_name ENABLE/DISABLE;
```

You can write this code in a stored procedure and then get it executed using some out-of-the-database program, e.g. PHP, JAVA, SHELL etc. (depending on your architecture) that supports time driven execution

Answer (score 0):

DBMS_LOCK.SLEEP might to the trick:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/d_lock.htm#ARPLS66781

Comment: Well this can be added inside the trigger code, but it will execute only when the trigger is fired. OP's question is to stop trigger from executing.

Comment: Ah, I didn't update to see the further comments on the question. So, this is of no use.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily delay an action by creating a job.

For example, your trigger may call `DBMS_JOB.submit` to create a job to run at a particular time (e.g. 10 minutes after the current time). The job needs to be created with the name of a procedure that needs to be run. For example, you might create a procedure that takes a record ID as a parameter.

The nice thing about DBMS_JOB is that it is transactional - so if your triggering statement is rolled back, the job will also be rolled back.

The downside is that the job will never start until after the statement that created it is committed.